# Is there a way for the Telegram bot to read the messages first and not allow them in the chat? I'm using Aiogram

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

Is this functionality possible in any way?

I'm using aiogram 3x, just in case there's a solution available. Thank you!

What I expect:

1. User sends a message to a group
2. Bot sees it first and deletes it
3. Nobody else in the group is aware that there was a message sent

Comment: No, this is not possible. Messages are distributed to all chat members at the same time. Best you can do is delete the message immediately, but this can't prevent that someone sees it.